# SET vs NIC Teaming for Hyper-V Switch

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

For a basic setup a single 2016 Hyper-V server and one virtual switch with 4 NIC's is there a benefit of switching to SET vs using standard NIC Teaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you clarify what types of networking and count of switches you are using? Basically, SET is RDMA enabled teaming which is designed for multiple switches with RDMA (tree architecture). In case if it simple NIC's (1 GbE) there is no reason for using them just for management, NIC teaming with configured LACP do their job.
"A huge benefit of SET over LBFO is that SET enables the NICs to run as converged which means the NICs support regular IP traffic in addition to RDMA"
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-virtual-switch/rdma-and-switch-embedded-teaming

http://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/what-switch-embedded-teaming-windows-server-2016

Comment: my setup is extremely basic. The nic i'm using is an i340-T4 (dedicated to hyper-v with another adapter for managing the host). I've got just one virtual switch and one physical switch. I don't use RDMA. My main curiosity is will SET vs NIC teaming maybe provide better latency or lower cpu overhead?

Comment: Sadly that was wrong even in 2012 (with server 2012 actually). These days it seems they are identical with a little note telling me "more ressources are available for Hyper-V in SET" - and that is it. Not quantified at all.